# Mac app shrinks when copied to USB

Tags: macos, file-transfer, code-signing

I have a Mac app that is 443,245,675 bytes.

When I copy it to a flash drive, the copied version is only 443,239,527 bytes and the app package becomes invalid (`spctl -a` fails).

This difference (6148 bytes) is the size of a `.DS_Store` file exactly, but none seems to exist in the app package. My hidden files are visible and I've looked using `ls -l` — there's no `.DS_Store` file there.

What's going on here and how do I fix it so my app doesn't become invalidated every time it's copied? Note that the app still runs even though `spctl` fails. That said, should I even worry about this?

Comment: What formats are your flash and source disks ?

Comment: I suspect your USB is FAT and your main disk HFS+. This is why distributions of apps are usually done by creating a .dmg to contain the app

Comment: You're right! The USB was FAT32. That narrows down the solutions considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thumb drive is likely formatted as FAT32 (or just FAT if older).

Copying the app to something that isn't formatted as Mac OS Extended, probably resulted in the loss of things like file owner, permissions, etc, that may have been needed to run/validate it with the system.

Either consider

1. Packaging it as a .dmg, or
2. If this is something you might need often, you could reformat the thumb drive as HFS+ (after backing up anything important on it).  Consider copying the app file with the flag to preserve settings:

   cp -p source_file target_thumb_drive

Comment: Thanks. The drive was FAT32. I'll try getting creative with the copy over.

Comment: For anyone having this problem in the future: My dmg installer would install the app on a FAT32 drive, leaving behind certain permissions native to Mac. What I did was zip the app, have the installer move it to the drive, and then run a post-installation script to unzip it and then delete the zip from the drive. What's left is a Mac app with permissions intact.

Comment: @corpico why not just do the standard OSX thing of distributing a .dmg

Comment: @corpico I'm glad to hear you got it working.  I'm happy I was able to help.